# Perform POST from Browser URL

Tags: node.js, rest, api, post, postman

I have a functionality of verifying a user by clicking a link from **Email**. I have field in Mongo `User` Collection called `Active`. This is a boolean. when User register, Active will be false. When they click the link active will change to true. My issue is that link is working well in postman but not working in browser URL.

**My Code**

```
  verify = (req, res) => {
    User.update({ email: req.query.mail }, { $set: { active: true } }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
       res.send(user);
      }
    });
  }
```

My API: `POST api/user/verifySignin`

My Link: `http://localhost:3000/api/user/verifySignin?mail=abc@xyz.com`

I used this link in browser URL its not working, But I used in POSTMAN its working. Help me, where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can't make post requests from an URL directly in your browser, you need to either use an XMLHTTP request library like fetch or use a `<form action="http://localhost:3000/api/user/verifySignin?mail=abc@xyz.com" method="post">`

Comment: Is it is possible to add this in Nodemailer HTML ?

Comment: Of course, just use the fetch api to make your requests https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0):

> 1. try $http to pass the url

$http.post(http://localhost:3000/api/user/verifySignin)

Comment: Any reference link please